# How to play a video on videoView by a link address in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have this code:

```
String SrcPath = "http://blog.mehdirahimi.ir/wp-content/uploads/egg_heart.mp4";
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

and I want to play a video by a link address that stored in database, now I have problem with this code that I getting "Can't play video"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, my problem was that i dont add internet permission to android application.

for solve this problem just add this cod to your manifest.xml file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

use in manifest.xml follow like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```